# Service always binds to 127.0.0.1 when started by systemd?

Tags: systemd

my Unit File:

```
[Unit]

Description=TW5 Bacula Wiki
After=nginx.service
Requires=nginx.service
[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=5000
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/tiddlywiki /home/pi/tw5/linux/bacula --server 9094 $:/core/save/all text/plain text/html "" "" %H
User=Tw5
Group=Tw5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I start it I get the following:

```
Jun  8 21:16:57 wiki tiddlywiki[1037]: Serving on 127.0.0.1:9094
```

I was hoping instead that it would bind to the ip of the DNS name (`%H`) ip but that didn't work either.

I've also tried 0.0.0.0 in the command without any luck.

I also used  [this](http://tiddlywiki.com/#:Commands%20ServerCommand%20Community) as a reference for the command that runs the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you still need help with this, but this is what I did to get it working:

Create a unit file ( i.e. /etc/systemd/system/tiddlywiki.service)

```
[Unit]
Description=TiddlyWiki
After=syslog.target

[Service]
SyslogIdentifier=tiddlywiki
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
EnvironmentFile=/etc/tiddlywiki.conf
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tiddlywiki $WIKI $SERVER $PORT $ROOT $RENDER $SERVE $HOST

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Add your arguments to the `EnvironmentFile` located at `/etc/tiddlywiki.conf`

```
WIKI=/home/pi/tw5/linux/bacula
SERVER=--server
PORT=9094
ROOT=$:/core/save/all
RENDER=text/plain
SERVE=text/html
HOST=%H
```

Restart the `tiddlywiki.service` file and you should be good to go.